# Link to a page with submit button without form action/forms within forms

Tags: html, forms, submit, action

I am working on a php/html/js page.

I have two buttons.  They both need to submit the same form data, but I want one to link to another page(which needs the form data from this page) and one to do something on the current page.

I don't know how to make the linkage button go to another page AND post the same form data AND not lose the post data (using something like header('Location:')).

I can't set form action="page.php" because then both buttons would change pages.  A form within a form doesn't work either.

My setup is as follows:

```
<form method="post" action="" name="aform">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="submit" name="button" value"Clickit"></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="button2" value"Click to link"></td>
</table>
</form>
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: Different buttons alone won't work. You'll need JavaScript.

Comment: Use the JS to build the page I want to link to, or use it to perform the submit?

Comment: You'll need it to handle the different button submit actions.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is way to late, and OP has, hopefully, figured out a solution back in 2012. 
But in case someone finds this through search, here's a possible solution:

Use the formaction attribute of the button element:

```
<form action="/actions/1" method="post">
    <button type="submit">Submit to default action</button>
    <button formaction="/actions/2" type="submit">Submit to action 2</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Put a separate form within each `<td>`:

```
<table>
<tr><td><form action="action1.php"><input type="submit" name="button"></form></td>
    <td><form action="action2.php"><input type="submit" name="button2"></form></td>
</table>
```

Comment: as far as I know forms cannot be part of <table>, <tr> or <td>